# On change dropdown list hide the thrid option is not working

Tags: jquery, html

This is the Js Code

```
$('body').delegate('change', '#received_type', function() {
    var received = $('#received_type').val()
    if (received === 1) {
        $('#check').removeClass('hide')
        $('#check').show();
        $('#dd').hide();
    } else if (received === 3) {
        $('#dd').hide();
        $('#check').hide();
    } else if (received === 2) {
        $('#dd').removeClass('hide')
        $('#dd').show();
        $('#check').hide();
    }
})
```

This Html Code

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputSuccess">
                            Received Type :
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <select class="form-control" name="received_type" id="received_type" required="required">
                                <option value="">Select Received Type</option>
                                <option value="1">Check</option>
                                <option value="2">DD</option>
                                <option value="3">Cash</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/><br/>
                    <div class="form-group hide" id="check">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputSuccess">
                            Check Number :
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="check_no" id="check_number" placeholder="Check Number" required="required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group hide" id="dd">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputSuccess">
                            DD Number :
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dd_no" id="dd_number" placeholder="DD Number" required="required" />
                        </div>                            
                    </div>
```

My Question is

Whenever I select the Check or DD, then textbox working properly but when I select the Cash option then DD or Check Must be hidden but its not working.

Please suggest.

Thanx In Advance.

Comment: There's nothing working actually: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/acf1umv6/

Comment: You're missing the use of `$(this)`: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/acf1umv6/1/

Comment: Thank U Sir for the great advice now it is working perfectly -  MelanciaUK.

Answer (score 0):

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.
> [Source](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Then change `var received = $('#received_type').val()` to var received = `$(this).val()`.

The value is given as a string, not an integer. So `received === 1` won't match. Instead use `received == 1` so it checks if the value is the same, but won't look at the type of the value.

```
$('body').on('change', '#received_type', function() {
    var received = $(this).val()
    
    if (received == 1) {
        $('#check').removeClass('hide')
        $('#check').show();
        $('#dd').hide();
    } else if (received == 3) {
        $('#dd').hide();
        $('#check').hide();
    } else if (received == 2) {
        $('#dd').removeClass('hide')
        $('#dd').show();
        $('#check').hide();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ojgjor21/)

## Optimization

As for optimizing your code. Rather change your select (values) to:

```
<select class="form-control" name="received_type" id="received_type" required="required">
    <option value="">Select Received Type</option>
    <option value="check">Check</option>
    <option value="dd">DD</option>
    <option value="cash">Cash</option>
</select>
```

Then you can change your jQuery function to:

```
$('body').on('change', '#received_type', function() {
    var received = $(this).val();
    
    $('.form-group.hide').hide();
    $('#'+received).show();
});
```

It first hides all elements that have both `.form-group` and `.hide` class and then shows the id that is selected.

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/ojgjor21/1/)